# upload image in database using vbscript in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, image, vbscript, upload, binary

I want to upload an image in database in form of binary. I have code written in asp. But Now, I want to write it in asp.net using `vbscript` language.

Now, the scenario is:
   I have a html file control, by choosing image from that control, I will allow user to submit image. There is an `asp:button` for submitting and I want to write a Subroutine on it's `OnClick` event.

Now can anyone please help to me write a Subroutine with proper Syntax of VbScript.

Comment: Kindly Format your Question...

Comment: Hi, @Rajesh, I just want to know the proper code for inserting an image in form of binary into database. I am using VbScript on asp.net platform. Hope you are getting my point.